# jQuery Framework to attach comments to images, like Facebook or Flickr

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app I want to add feedback over uploaded Images.
Does anybody know of a Javascript / jQuery / Rails Solution that allows easily to attach a comment over an Image?  Like for example here on Flickr: http://www.flickr.com/photos/galt-museum/4112917253/

I think Flickr uses YUI but I have no experience with that, I'd prefer something from the jQuery world!

It is important that the comment can be attached to a given position on that image.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1839-jQuery-Photo-Tagger-Plugin-For-Flickr-Style-Photo-Tagging.htm
Official project page : http://www.bennadel.com/projects/jquery-photo-tagger.htm

Answer (score 1):

Finally i went with: http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/